# Lotus Notes Calendar - mark-private field Programmatically

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

In notes calendar by  removing "**$PublicAccess**" field by script we are making calendar entry as private.
In calendar it shows  icon of private ,
also in details it shows message like "**This entry is marked private.**"
But while opening entry the the field mark-private is un-checked 
even after it's private .

So,Is there any way to check that check-box.

Like,If check box is checked it should be private and when unchecked it is should be public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The item that is used internally is the item $PublicAccess as you found out.

But the item is never "directly" set in the UI. The item used in the UI is called `OrgConfidential`. If you set this item to "1" then in the backend the $PublicAccess- Item is removed... For "mimicking" this programmatically you need to set frontend- item and backend- item accordingly: Set OrgConfidential = "1", and the UI will reflect the backend correctly.